# Google sheets find MIN time of min price

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, min, google-sheets-query

Given the following data:

> ```
> 123 2020-06-22 23:00:00
> 124 2020-06-22 23:30:00
> 121 2020-06-23 00:00:00
> ```

I want the hour/minute of the minimum price in a Google Sheet. I tried using without success:

```
=QUERY(A:B,"select hour(B), min(A) group by todate(B)")
=QUERY(A:B,"select B, min(A) group by todate(B)")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A:B); 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

or for each date:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT({A:B, DATEVALUE(B:B)}), 9^9, 2, 3, 1), 9^9, 2)
```

[image]